# How to load .log.gz compressed file from Cloud Storage to big query?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have multiple compressed .log.gz file coming into my Cloud Storage. I was using Google Data Prep to handle the files then transferring them to Big Query but now the size of data is quite large, which is increasing the time and cost using the Data Prep. I want to get those .log.gz files to Big Query to able to do task manually when needed.  Is there a way to connect them to Big query?

I tried Big Query transfer service but it doesn't work on compressed files.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, you can load CSV, JSON, Avro, Parquet, ORC, Cloud Datastore exports, Cloud Firestore exports from Cloud Storage to Big Query.

However, if the gz files contain the supported formats, then they can be imported to Big Query directly. However, there are some limitations like the location of the bucket. These limitations can be checked [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage#limitations).

You can also find how to load the data [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage#gcs-uri).

In the same [documentation link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data#loading_compressed_and_uncompressed_data), you can find more information about loading compressed data.

Comment: Hey @siamsot, Thanks for the reply. My compressed file contains json format data but the issue is that it contains dictionaries and big query does not support the json file containing dictionaries. Is there a way around that?

Comment: At the moment, dictionaries can't be accepted as seen [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#limitations). However, you can consider using Dataflow to prepare your data with [this](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/data-science-preprocessing) tutorial. However, I'm not sure how costly will be in time and cost as this was also your initial problem but I think it's worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with structured logs looking into this now, log files are usually plain text files separated by some kind of separator (example: white spaces), which means they can be treated as CSVs when loading. They can be loaded into BigQuery with the `bq` tool and the right parameters.

Example:
`bq load --replace --source_format=CSV --autodetect --field_delimiter=" " your_dataset.your_table gs://path/to/your/file.log.gz`

You can schedule this on a cron job, cloud scheduler, airflow, whatever. You can also translate those parameters into whatever API/SDK you are using.

As for the compression, BigQuery will automatically decompress the files.